# How to do nested preload of models in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix app where I have Polls, that have many Candidates, that have many Votes.

in my controller I load the poll like this:

```
poll = Repo.get_by!(Poll, url: String.downcase(url))
    |> Repo.preload([:candidates])
# and set it for the view like this
render(conn, "poll.html", poll: poll)
```

In the view the Candidates are there. The problem is, that the Votes, which belong to a specific Candidate, are not preloaded in the view.

How can I achieve this? What's the syntax for nested preloads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do nested preloads, you can pass nested a nested list as argument like this:

```
poll = Repo.get_by!(Poll, url: String.downcase(url))
    |> Repo.preload([candidates: [:votes]])
```

Comment: thanks, works like charme! May I ask you where you found this information?

Comment: @RedRoosterMobile Search for "Nested associations" on this page: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3